# How to make an ETH transfer from a contract that appears as an ETH transaction on the destination address?

Tags: solidity, ether, rinkeby

I'm learning Solidity, and I've created a very basic contract that sends Ether from the contract to another address.

My contract works, and ETH is being transfered (I'm on Rinkeby). ETH is subtracted from the contract wallet and appears in the dest address. I'm also logging the the transaction with an Event.

But, there is no record of the tx on the destination address. Is this the expected outcome? Is it possible to transfer ETH from a contract to an address that appears as an ETH transaction on the destination address?

For reference, my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract SimpleSend {  

uint public value;
address public dest;

event Init(address _dest, string _logos);
event LogWithdrawal(address _from, uint _amount);

function SimpleSend(address _dest) public {
    dest = _dest;
    emit Init(_dest);
}

function() payable public {
    value = msg.value;
    emit LogWithdrawal(msg.sender, msg.value);
    dest.transfer(value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear because the wallets don't show incoming transactions unless is a contract wallet. If you are receiving the ether all is good!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does this mean, by design, when Eth is transfered to another address from a contract, there's no record of the transfer on the blockchain? The Eth just appears in the destination acct?

Comment: there is record on the block chain of course, is just that wallets like mist wont show the incoming transaction. But there are another type of wallets ( available in mist for instance) called contract wallets, these will show the incoming transactions.